# How to create an animate-on-update Stacked Bar chart using Chart.js(or Chartist)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, chartist.js

I've been trying to create a stacked bar chart in Chart.js as it does the slide animation on every update which is nice, as opposed to Chartist which has easily creatable stacked bar charts but has to recreate the chart on every update (I've tried to animate it, but I'm too stupid to do it for some reason).

The code I'm using is almost literally a rip from jtblin's github, but for some reason it doesn't stack for me: the bars just sit next to each other. Here's the link to his chart: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/examples/stacked-bars.html. The controller link: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/examples/app.js.

Please find my code below, and please tell what am I doing wrong?

```
function chartJsWaveCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.labels = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    $scope.type = 'StackedBar';
    $scope.series = ['2015', '2016'];
    $scope.options = {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          stacked: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          stacked: true
        }]
      }
    };

    $scope.data = [
      [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
    ];
}
```

The original framework comes from blur-admin, if that is of any value.

Images depicting how it displays:

Mine:
[image: my non-stacked bar chart using chart.js]
Jtblin's:
[image: jtblin's stacked bar chart using chart.js]

**Please note**(and I think this may be the crux of the problem)**:** I'm using Chart.JS 1.0.2.

**Alternatively**, if someone could please tell me how to animate-on-update using Chartist, that would be great as well. It updates fine, it is stacked fine, has everything I want, but I can't get it to animate. I would presume I would have to do a .on('draw', ), but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. Stacked bars were added in Chart.js 2.0.0, and as such they're not present in Chart.js 1.0.2.

Source: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.0.0

That's annoying ¬_¬